# Child function with additional conditions

Tags: python

Say I have the following:

```
class Parent(object):
    [...]
    def func(self, list):
        for item in list:
            if condition1:
                do something

class Child(Parent):
    [...]
    def func(self, list):
        for item in list:
            if condition1 and condition2:
                do something
```

What would be an elegant way to add **condition2** to *func* without having to recopy the entire function? Note that I actually have two additional conditions in nested 'ifs'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have access to Parent, you could do

```
class Parent(object):
    [...]
    def _condition(self, whatever):
        return condition1
    def func(self, list):
        for item in list:
            if self._condition(...):
                do something

class Child(Parent):
    [...]
    def _condition(self, whatever):
        return condition1 and condition2
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way would be to evaluate the condition in an other method and override in the child:

```
class Parent(object):
    [...]
    def func(self, list):
        for item in list:
            if self.test(item):
                do something

    def test(self, item):
        return condition1

class Child(Parent):
    [...]
    def test(self, item):
        return super(Child, self).test(list) and condition2
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a new method (function) that does the comparison (returns *condition1* on *Parent* and *condition1 and condition2* on *Child*). You would only have to modify that function in the child class.

Sorry buy I cannot write an example because I don't know Python :P

Comment: Answers are better received when they have example code, and his answer came at the same time as yours, so you didn't get a chance to get upvoted before his arrived.

Answer (score 1):

```
from functools import partial

class Parent(object):
    [...]
    def func(self, list, condition = lambda item: condition1):
        for item in list:
            if condition(item):
                do something

class Child(Parent):
    [...]

    def func(self, list): 
        super(Child, self).func(list, condition = lambda item: condition1 and condition2)
```

if you only want to vary that one condition, or

```
class Parent(object):
    [...]
    def func(self, list):
        for item in list:
            self.whatever(item)

    @staticmethod
    def whatever(item):
        if condition1:
            do something
class Child(Parent):
    [...]
    @staticmethod
    def whatever(item):
        if condition1 and condition2:
            do something
```

if you want to vary multiple things in the loop. `do something` can also be another `staticmethod` on `Parent` if that is the same in both.

Comment: I posted my question hoping to get an answer that would teach me something new and/or remind me of different ways to approach this simple problem. You achieved just that. Even though I can't accept your answer, thank you.

Comment: Glad to help.  I like `partial` for this because you don't need to clutter up your class with any additional methods, and if you want to change `func`, you actually override `func`, not some other method.

Comment: So I'm using the optional lambda argument, but whenever I try to use partial I get the following error:
TypeError: unbound method *func()* must be called with *Child* instance as first argument (got *some argument* instance instead)

If I drop partial and write:
    `def func(self, list):
    super(Child, self).func(list, condition = lambda item: condition1 and condition2)`   
Then it works like a charm. Are you sure that calling a child instance with .func(...) works in the way you wrote it?

Comment: I actually left something out. I saw your partial, deleted comment and fixed it, then realized an easier way -- and rewrote it exactly how you did it in your finished comment (before seeing it :).